# Which two Indian states lifted the ban on The Da Vinci Code in or after 2006?

Tags: censorship, dan-brown, the-da-vinci-code

According to the Wikipedia article about [Dan Brown's *The Da Vinci Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_Da_Vinci_Code&oldid=1055718517#Lawsuits) (emphasis mine),

> Possibly the largest reaction [against the novel] occurred in Kolkata, India, where a group of around 25 protesters "stormed" Crossword bookstore, pulled copies of the book from the racks and threw them to the ground. On the same day, a group of 50–60 protesters successfully made the Oxford Bookstore on Park Street decide to stop selling the book "until the controversy sparked by the film's release was resolved".<sup>[38]</sup> Thus in 2006, seven Indian states (Nagaland, Punjab, Goa, Tamil Nadu, Andhra Pradesh) banned the release or exhibition of the Hollywood movie The Da Vinci Code (as well as the book).<sup>[39]</sup> **Later, two states lifted the ban under high court order.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>**

Which Indian states (the article mentions five states by name) lifted the ban against the novel and when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seven [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_union_territories_of_India_by_population) which banned *The Da Vinci Code* are listed as follows with linked news sources (the date in each case is the date of the linked article, not the date of the ban):

- **Nagaland** ([24 May 2006, The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/may/24/books.india)). May have been the first state to ban it, as this news article is earlier than the others and no other states are mentioned there.
- **Meghalaya** and **Andhra Pradesh** ([2 June 2006, Now Running](https://www.nowrunning.com/news/bollywood/the-da-vinci-code-banned-in-more-states/6795/story.htm)).
- **Tamil Nadu** ([3 June 2006, Irish Examiner](https://www.irishexaminer.com/lifestyle/arid-30261720.html)). Claimed to be the fourth state to ban it, although the first three aren't listed in this article.
- **Goa** and **Kerala** ([3 June 2006, East Bay Times](https://www.eastbaytimes.com/2006/06/02/7-of-indias-29-states-ban-da-vinci-code/)). This article claims Andhra Pradesh to be the seventh state to ban it.
- **Punjab** ([13 June 2006, CBC](https://www.cbc.ca/news/entertainment/indian-court-rejects-ban-on-da-vinci-code-1.618415)). Mentioned together with some of the others: "seven states, including Punjab, Goa, Tamil Nadu and Nagaland".

The information about which two states lifted the ban is also to be found on Wikipedia, although [not on the page that you were looking at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_banned_in_India): **Andhra Pradesh** and **Tamil Nadu**.

> HYDERABAD: The Andhra Pradesh High Court on Wednesday quashed the ban on the film The Da Vinci Code, holding the state government's June 1 order as "a highly irrational restriction on freedom of speech and expression."
>
> <sub>-- [22 June 2006, Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/hyderabad/hc-quashes-ban-on-da-vinci-code/articleshow/1669485.cms)</sub>

> Maintaining that the state had no compelling reasons to justify the violation of fundamental right of freedom of expression, the Madras High Court on Friday allowed the screening of controversial film *The Da Vinci Code* in Tamil Nadu and quashed a government order suspending its release.
>
> <sub>-- [8 July 2006, Rediff News](https://www.rediff.com/news/2006/jul/08tn.htm)</sub>

Note that some of the above sources refer to the *film* rather than the novel, and some of them do not clearly distinguish between the film and the novel, referring only to the work title.